# performing Correlation test on a dataframe with multiple comparision for each row

Tags: r, pandas, statistics

I have a  data frame with 67 rows and 96 columns, in which I have duplicated row name with the values for each of those row varying from the 48th column and so I need to run a correlation test for each row. This is how my data frame looks like,

```
   Sample   P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  F1  F2  F3  F4  F5
AS1_1   0.474181    0   2.541416    0.931405    3.679168    0.0442751   0.0582329   0.0399943   0.0397949   0.0389702
AS1_2   0.474181    0   2.541416    0.931405    3.679168    0.0648574   0.0733045   0.0599727   0.0542742   0.0795781
AS1_3   0.474181    0   2.541416    0.931405    3.679168    0.0418037   0.0447637   0.0329602   0.0366981   0.0391166
AS1_4   0.474181    0   2.541416    0.931405    3.679168    0.0842857   0.106061    0.0741478   0.0655408   0.0960092
RDA_1   0.426323    0.186972    0.371125    0.353353    0   0.183682    0.236717    0.204065    0.21347 0.158275
RDA_2   0.426323    0.186972    0.371125    0.353353    0   0.762271    0.157697    0.711849    0.773907    0.162249
RDA_3   0.426323    0.186972    0.371125    0.353353    0   0.65933 0.555187    0.716199    0.614248    0.134922
RDA_4   0.426323    0.186972    0.371125    0.353353    0   0.0757848   0.0806026   0.0850364   0.0956196   0.0527733
RDA_5   0.426323    0.186972    0.371125    0.353353    0   0.0505727   0.0709043   0.0481335   0.0389085   0.036532
```

The rows for example AS1_* and RDA_* has same values until the 5th column and then it's different, and I need to find the correlation of each row between first (P1..P5) 5 column versus second five columns (F1..F5) as values are different to find a good correlation and plot it.

So far I have transposed the data frame and I tried with the following script in R but it's throwing me error,

```
x=read.table('df',sep='\t',header=T)
x=t(x)


   for(gene in colnames(x))
{

gnamex <- paste0(gene,"_Beta")
gnamey <- paste0(gene,"_FPKM")

plot(x[,gnamex],x[,gnamey],main=paste0(gene,"\ncor= ",round(cor(x[,gnamex],x[,gnamey]), digits=3),"\np< ",round(cor.test(x[,gnamex],x[,gnamey])$p.value,digits=3)),xlab="Beta values",ylab="FPKM")
abline(lm(x[,gnamex]~x[,gnamey]), col="red")
lines(lowess(x[,gnamex],x[,gnamey]), col="blue")

}
```

But its throwing me following error message.

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, , gnamex) : undefined columns selected
```

Any help or better solution would be really great, both python and R is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: I'm assuming row 'RDA_5' column 'P5' equal to 0.0656101 is a typo?

Comment: The problem is that you're appending `_Beta` and `_FPKM` to the variables that you're trying to use to select the columns, but with those suffixes they no longer match the actual column names. There are therefore undefined column names that you're selecting. In general this doesn't make sense though because even if it didn't mess up the column identification *you're just taking 2 copies of the same column* and trying to plot it and analyze it. I think what you want to do is to take **rownames** and column names instead of just column names. But even that would only work if it were square.

Comment: @piRSquared Yes, sorry its a typo.

Comment: @Hack-R , thanks you for suggestion, would be great if you could guide me a little bit there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
genes_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.Sample.str.split('_').values.tolist())

P = df.filter(like='P').set_index(genes_idx)
P
```

[image]

```
F = df.filter(like='F').set_index(genes_idx)
F
```

[image]

```
P.T.corrwith(F.T.set_index(P.columns)).unstack()
```

[image]